# Is CUDA installation necessary to use GPU while running NLP models eg. BERT at local machine

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, nvidia, bert-language-model

Does someone need a CUDA toolkit to use local GPU while executing NLP models like BERT or Tensorflow library has the capability to trigger the local machine GPU on its own without extra code to be written(for GPU processing instead of CPU)?

Comment: Please clarify *exactly* what your question is; "*Is CUDA installation necessary to use GPU in Deep Learning?*" and "*can one carry forward the DL programming without CUDA?*" are two different (and quite unrelated) questions.

Comment: Sorry for not a clear query. But my question was related to using my laptop's GPU while working on deep learning (e.g. NLP models). will that library(TensorFlow) handle the triggering of GPU be default or it needs some toolkit like cuda. Note: Before I practiced on google collab for GPU related execution.

Comment: Please do not attempt to clarify in the comments; **edit & update** your question instead, focusing on the exact issue and removing or rephrasing possible ambiguities (I have pointed out some of them).

Comment: Still unclear; capability to trigger *what*? usage? installation?

Comment: In short (see also answers below): to use an NVIDIA GPU for DL, you need CUDA. There is always the option to use only the CPU, in which case you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR :

if You are asking is it necessary to have Cuda installation in order to utilize your NVIDIA-GPU in a Deep Learning framework, it depends. Pytorch ships the necessary Cuda libs and you do not need to have it installed.
Tensorflow on the other hand seems to require it.
However, also note that you may not be using the GPU as it may be running on your CPU.

If you are asking whether CUDA is necessary to do Deep-learning related computation,
then the answer is no it is not.

### Long Explanation :

There are several options that are available when you need or want to use your GPU's capabilities to run a deep model.

Apart from customized hardware, software-wise, OpenCL, AMD's RoCM, ONNX, Microsofts DirectML, Apache's TVM, Intel's OpenVINO, ... are a few to name that can be used as backends to utilize your GPU's(and other hardwares) capabilities.

Please note that although you have such options their support for all use-cases is not yet there. That is you need to consult their latest documentation to see what's possible and what's not.
For example, RoCm does not support all AMDs GPUs (it does not support integrated ones as of now for example).
The RoCm support does not exist in former Deep-Learning frameworks such as Caffe (though an OpenCL version still exists)
This also applies to the other toolkits, for example, MS DML has support for tensorflow(1,15) as of now and it doesn't yet support the latest version, also it's still in beta) and there is no port for Pytorch for example.
You can, however, Run PyTorch models through ONNX and use DML backend form there but then again it has its own set of issues to deal with.
So yes the possibility of using GPUs without CUDA is there, but they still have couple of years IMHO to catch up to the current status of CUDA.  if you want an enjoyable experience without any headaches stick to CUDA unless your specific use case is supported by some of these toolkits.

Comment: No, afaik, Pytorch is *not* shipping the low-level CUDA library, as pytorch only installs Python library. And the CUDA lib is rather at the OS level.

Comment: @xtof54 see [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-for-cuda-10-2/65524/2?u=shisho_sama) if you don't want to give it a try yourself

Comment: Thanks for the link: I didn't knew they put the CUDA libs alongside with pytorch: that puzzles me tbh ! I'm wondering how they did it. I'll try and investigate that later. Thanks for the info.

Comment: A more accurate tl;dr would be an unconditional **yes** to the (title) question; the fact that in some cases you have to install it yourself while in some other cases the framework can install it for you is an interesting distinction but secondary to the (title) question: CUDA is always needed in order to exploit the GPU.

Comment: If they have an NVIDIA-GPU yes. otherwise its a no! (and yes if we factor the installation by the user or the distribution of cuda binaries, cuda for the frameworks that are built for nvidia-gpus is required.

Comment: Fair point - question is quite unclear in itself, it was tagged as `nvidia` though, and I guess we can comfortably assume it is about NVIDIA GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you can train Tensorflow or Pytorch deep learning models without CUDA, just on CPU.
- But you must install the CUDA libraries in order to be able to train your model on GPU.

The standard versions of Tensorflow and Pytorch are python libraries, while the CUDA library is a system-level lib, so it is often installed independently, although Pytorch seems indeed to provide a binary that installs it as well (cf. @Rika's answer)

Comment: For Pytorch you don't need to install them unless you want a cuda version that the pytorch binaries are not built against by default. in which case, you should build it from source and only then you need to have that specific cuda installed locally.